# SSH agent forwarding, multiple hop

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

**I tested this setup with Linux origin machine - everything is the same - only the first hop can use keys from origin machine.**

#### Initial problem

I'm trying to set up SSH agent forwarding with multiple hops. My local machine is Windows, with putty and pageant, all Linux machines are Debian 7.

The problem is that my private keys, originating from windows, work only on the first hop.
Private key added on any the first machine works everywhere.

First hop machine is called 'vpn1', second 'www1'.
'vpn1' is connected to internet and to intranet(10.1.0.1).
'www1' is connected only to intranet(10.1.0.10).
'vpn1' adds key(enbyted@vpn1.enbyted.org) using 'ssh-add', this key shows in pageant.

#### Debugging

I see all 3 keys in `ssh-add -L`:

```
ssh-rsa [pubkey-1] git@home.enbyted.org //This is github key originating from Windows
ssh-rsa [pubkey-2] enbyted@home.robotronika.pl //This is SSH key originating from Windows
ssh-rsa [pubkey-3] enbyted@vpn1.enbyted.org //This is SSH key originating from 'vpn1'
```

When I try to `ssh -v -T git@github.com` from 'vpn1'

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: git@home.enbyted.org
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
```

When I try to `ssh -v -T git@github.com` from 'www1'

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: git@home.enbyted.org
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering RSA public key: enbyted@home.robotronika.pl
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering RSA public key: enbyted@vpn1.enbyted.org
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/enbyted/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/enbyted/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/enbyted/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

The same goes with ssh to hosts that accept only 'enbyted@home.robotronika.pl' key. But I can SSH with as many hops as I like with 'enbyted@vpn1.enbyted.org'. Of course, the same goes for git commands.

#### Configurations

My `~/.ssh/config` (same on all servers):

```
Host 10.1.0.*
    ForwardAgent yes

Host *
    ForwardAgent no
```

My `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (without comments, same on all servers):

```
Port <custom-port>
Protocol 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 768
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin no
StrictModes yes
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
IgnoreRhosts yes
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
HostbasedAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
UsePAM yes
```

#### Questions

- So, why is that?
- What am I doing wrong?

Also it's really strange, that on 'www1' github offers two auth methods - password and publickey ... I'm sure that 'www1' SSHing to github.com is connecting to the same server as 'vpn1'.

#### Update #1: network setup on image

Please note, that image is from [article](http://sshmenu.sourceforge.net/articles/transparent-mulithop.html), but pretty much shows my setup.

[image: Network setup image]

So, I have 2 keys on my home PC, and one key on ruapehu (vpn1).

When I SSH to ruapehu from the home PC I can use all three keys just fine.
But when I do another ssh from ruapehu (vpn1) to aoraki (www1) I can use only the key from ruapehu.

And when I ssh from aoraki (www1) to any hosts below with any amount of hops only key from ruapehu works.

It doesn't if home PC is Windows with Putty + pageant or Linux with ssh-agent.

Comment: May be try to narrow it down by eliminating windows as first hop if possible. Use Linux for each hop to see if it works as expected.

Comment: @Ketan Everything works on the first hop(and local machine). On the second hop though I can't use keys originating from local machine(Windows).

Comment: @slm I didn't say that in OP. vpn1 and www1 are in 10.1.0.0/24 class. But I tried it and it didn't help.

Comment: @Enbyted Is it possible that Windows machine is not doing the ssh handshake properly? One way to test that would be to use Linux as first machine.

Comment: @Ketan it is *technically* possible, I use Putty and Pageant.
Key added by 'vpn1' is visible in pageant. I don't have linux machine handy at the moment, but I'll test it ASAP.

Comment: @slm Sorry, I thought it was obvious. I added that info to OP.

Comment: @Ketan I just tested it with git-bash, it's the same as putty.

Comment: @terdon I think the problem is on Linux side, but it's my first time with ssh-agent forwarding, so I may be wrong.
Currently I have separate private key for each machine, but it became hard to maintain on 100 machines.

Comment: It's an issue about a Windows machine communicating with a Linux one, so it's an issue about Windows. Both operating systems are on topic on our sister site [su], so just take the question there. You can flag for moderator attention (use the "flag" link under your post) and ask them to migrate or just delete here and post again there.

Comment: @terdon - Gilles says this is on-topic here.

Comment: @slm yes key added on 'vpn1' is working on all machines as it should. I'll test this setup from linux machine, so I can know whether it's Windows or Linux problem.

Comment: Looks like it's linux problem. Just tested it with linux origin machine. I'll update OP.

Comment: And I've also been overruled, looks like I'm wrong and connecting to a *nix machine makes this on topic. I will delete my previous comments and have retracted my close vote. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I've retracted my vote as well, and also removed comments. Apologies for the confusion too.

Comment: I would take a look at the `ssh_config` file on the vpn1 system then. `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`. Sounds like it might be overriding your forwarding of the agent.

Comment: @slm Since the machines that I'm testing it on are not yet deployed SSH config is pretty much default, expect for disabling root login. 
I don't see anything about ssh agent in there.
Also all of the machines that I'm testing this on are (as it goes for ssh config matters) the same and only keys from origin host aren't working after first hop. Give me a moment, I'll attach a image to OP describing my setup, maybe I wrote it unclear and that leads to confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue lies with the configuration of PuTTY. This forwards setting needs to be checked like so:

[image: ss of dialog]

#### References

- [How To SSH Hop With Key Forwarding from Windows](http://www.howtogeek.com/125364/how-to-ssh-hop-with-key-forwarding-from-windows/)

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I have it already checked. As I told in OP - I can use Windows private keys on first hop, but not on second, third, ...

Comment: Really old but you need to load your keys. You can use Pageant for this.

Comment: Really late reply, but I do use pageant (or ssh-agent on linux). All the keys are available on the first hop, just not any further.